# Matplotlib plt.xlabel() vs ax.set_xlabel()

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib

I am using some code that uses the singleton-version of matplotlib in Python, i.e. it has calls like

```
plt.figure()
...
plt.xlabel("abc")
```

I am trying to convert it to the functional/memory-less version:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
...
ax.set_xlabel("abc")
```

A couple questions:

- Is there an option to set the xlabel of an axes directly? Something
  like `ax.xlabel = "xlabel string"`?
- [From the documentation, it seems like this is not possible.](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#axis-labels-title-and-legend) (not
  even a private attribute we can set)
- Or is it always required to go through the setter? This has always
  confused me and struck me as non-Pythonic.
- Why did the API change going from `plt.xlabel()` to `ax.set_xlabel()`?

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib had the pyplot interface, and then later developed the object-oriented interface, as described in the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html).

The latter is now preferred, so use fig, ax = plt.subplots and then use the setter method on ax.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any idea why they decided to change the API though?